# Greek fire explosive I assume -- did an accident lead any inventor to consider using it as a propellant?

Tags: ancient-greece, technology

I would guess that occasionally pots of Greek fire did explode and if so, one would have seen how far shards were sent. Assuming this is true, did anyone suggest something like a cannon or a bomb meant to blast through a wall, not just spread fire?

Or maybe Greek fire does not explode.

Comment: It's not clear what Greek Fire actually was, but a likely candidate is some kind of petroleum-based substance, so it wouldn't just explode. Wikipedia gives a lot of details (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_fire), have you checked if there's any reference to explosions? Most combustible substances don't explode (or only under very special circumstances, like a build-up of gases) and it's actually generally hard to make things explode.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen: The wikipedia article does suggest that it could explode. But I could see users being fixed on the fire aspect and less interested in projecting shards except to the extent that such shards were themselves burning.

Comment: Can you add the relevant Wikipedia quote about explosion to your question? I must admit don't quite see where it is mentioned, but the article is very long and detailed, so it might help if you can show the evidence that it might have been an explosive.

Comment: To clarify, Wikipedia mentions "explosive" a few times but, as far as I can see, in connection with theories that are then dismissed. I couldn't see if there's good evidence.